# Proverb: a story explains best of all

Tags: proverbs

I've got a question and I realize that the easiest way to answer it is to tell a story which will explain why the things are going in this way.

However it does not look natural to start telling story when you are asked a question. I need some phrase or proverb to designate that this story is related. What is the best way to tell this?

Comment: Nice question. *"A picture is worth a thousand words"* conveys a similar concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words

Comment: @Antonio Please give the context of the situation, is the story an analogy? a proverb? a historical statement of why something is done ? In any event just saying  "Let me explain with this `insert type of story`" will probably be good enough.

Comment: You could simply say 'Let me illustrate [the question and its answer] with a story' - and tell your story. This is a common phrase used by teachers.

Comment: @Josh61 That is not really a similar concept. How is `A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words` even slightly related to starting an answer with a story? Are you suggesting they say that then start telling a story, because if someone did that to me  i would be very confused.

Comment: @123 - it is similar in the sense that instead of having a "story", there is  a "picture" to illustrate something that a thousand word could not do better.

Answer (score 2):

Consider ***[Thereby/Therein hangs a tale](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Thereby+hangs+a+tale)***

> (*British & Australian humorous*) something that you say when you have been asked about something that needs a long explanation

[The Free Dictionary]

***Usage:***

> *Your friend*: Why was Nutella invented?
>
> *You*: Ah! ***Thereby hangs a tale***... *{and then start to tell the tale which would clearly explain stuff to the OP}*